# Error BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT when writing from spark to MySql

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

I'm running simple code to write dataframe to the MySql db

```
  val mydf = //.. create some dataframe
   mydf
  .write
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
  .option("url",url)
  .option("dbtable",table)
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .save();
```

And as a result getting following error

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
```

Tried to add additional property , but it seems spark is ignoring that
.option(BINLOG_FORMAT,"MIXED")

Is there an option to set some property on spark level and not change the database definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option specified in spark documentation to change `BINLOG_FORMAT`.
You can check the possible options [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html).

From the exception message:

> InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.

`READ_UNCOMMITTED` is the default isolation in spark. You can try changing this option.